# How can I click space to pause the video without down the page in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ajax

I build custom video player using JavaScript and when I click Space to stop the video the page get down and I need to prevent this

My JavaScript code

```
      window.onkeydown = vidCtrl;

    function vidCtrl(e){
      const vid = document.querySelector('video')
      const key = e.code;

      if (key === 'ArrowLeft') {
    vid.currentTime -= 5;
    if (vid.currentTime < 0) {
      vid.pause();
      vid.currentTime = 0;
    }
  } else if (key === 'ArrowRight') {
    vid.currentTime += 5;
    if (vid.currentTime > vid.duration) {
      vid.pause();
      vid.currentTime = 0;
    }
  } else if (key === 'Space') {
    if (vid.paused || vid.ended) {
      vid.play();
    } else {
      vid.pause();
    }
  
  
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add `e.preventDefault()` when the user press the space button in order to prevent from the unwanted scroll

```
else if (key === 'Space') {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (vid.paused || vid.ended) {
      vid.play();
    } else {
      vid.pause();
    }
  
  
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try calling `e.preventDefault()` which will stop key events from doing their normal behavior, i.e. scrolling the page or typing a letter.

However you have to be careful. Adding an event listener to the ENTIRE window can cause a lot of side effects. What if someone is trying to do something as simple as typing a sentence into an input of your webpage? Only use `e.preventDefault()` on the window level if there are no other inputs or keyboard interactions the user could do on that page.